# VisualStateManager not setting attached properties Grid.Row and Grid.ColumnSpan in UWP application

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to change some attached properties using the VisualStateManager in a Windows 10 Universal App project but the setters aren't working. It's not setting the attached properties of my TopBarGrid element.

If you look below I'm using the parentheses notation in order to change the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.ColumnSpan` properties. But when I run the app, the properties are not being set when I enlargen the width. I'm expecting the Grid to move to that position.

Here is my code:

```
<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="wideState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="641" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="splitView.DisplayMode" Value="Inline"/>
                    <Setter Target="splitView.IsPaneOpen" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Target="togglePaneButton.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Target="appHeader.Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                    <Setter Target="PaneHeader.Margin" Value="6,12,0,0"/>
                    <Setter Target="TopBarGrid.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Target="TopBarGrid.(Grid.RowSpan)" Value="2"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="narrowState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="splitView.DisplayMode" Value="Overlay"/>
                    <Setter Target="togglePaneButton.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Target="PaneHeader.Margin" Value="60,12,0,0"/>
                    <Setter Target="searchForInfoBox.Width" Value="270"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="TopRowHeight" Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="TopBarGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <toolbars:TopHorizontalToolBar/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="LeftBarGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <toolbars:VerticalToolBar />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Sorry it's because I'm working on a VM and I cannot copy and paste the code.

Comment: Converted image to code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks fine, however, in both states, you are setting the `Row` and `ColumnSpan` of the `TopBarGrid` to the **same** values. That's why you won't see any changes.

Try removing one set from one state.

---

The reason you still don't see any changes is most likely because there's something wrong with your `Setter`s in your `narrowState`.

Try the following code, note that the `TopBarGrid` behaves correctly.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="wideState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="641" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="TopBarGrid.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="TopBarGrid.(Grid.RowSpan)" Value="2" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="narrowState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="TopBarGrid.Background" Value="Green" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="TopRowHeight" Height="80" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="TopBarGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Red" />
            <Grid x:Name="LeftBarGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

But as soon as I throw in more `Setter`s (e.g. `<Setter Target="PaneHeader.Margin" Value="60,12,0,0" />`) to the `narrowState`, it stops working. I know, `PaneHeader` wasn't even defined in my test page! But it also tells me that the `VSM` simply swallows the error for some reason.

So, try removing your `Setter`s and adding them back one to one to locate the bugged one. Then it would be a simple fix.

Comment: I tried removing one of them but it still does not work. I even moved the VSM to the top f my code. Not sure if that does anything scope-wise..

Comment: Forgot to mention, you also want to have your vsm under your root panel.

Comment: That was it. When I removed all the setters and added them one by one, things were working fine, until one of them made none of them work. The VSM does not report any errors. Why does it swallow the error? It's ver hard to debug that.

Comment: No idea lol. It seems to be able to report some of the errors but not all of them for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

@Ray As for **TopBarGrid.(Grid.Column)** you have to provide **PaneHeader.(FrameworkElement.Margin)**